# How do I get magento backend config xml data?

Tags: php, magento, config

I have a system.xml in my module, which starts with this:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <dev>
            <groups>
                <my_module>
                    <label>...
```

I want to get the value of this label, from a different module. How do I do it? My first thought, was `Mage::getConfig('sections/dev/groups/my_module/label')`, but this doesn't work - it seems the `<sections>` area of the config is not accessible. I also can't figure out where magento is loading this value, which it must do at some point, or it wouldn't be able to display it.

To be completely clear: I am not trying to get the config data value as stored in the core_config_data table, that's no trouble. I want to be able to get the other attributes relating to it - like the group label, or the sort order of the fields, and to do that I need to be able to read the `<sections>` area of the config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `system.xml` files are never merged with the global configuration.  They're only loaded when Magento builds the user interface for the

```
System -> Configuration
```

section of the backend admin application.  Other than that the application has no use for them.

If you want to grab the label, you'll need to load the full `system.xml` configuration yourself.  Something like this should work.

```
//load and merge `system.xml` files
$config = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml');        

//grab entire <sections/> node
var_dump($config->getNode('sections')->asXml());        

//grab label from a specific option group as a string
var_dump((string)$config->getNode('sections/dev/groups/restrict/label'));
```

As mentioned in another answer in this thread, there's also an `adminhtml/config` model class which wraps some of this logic in a `getSection` method, so you could do something like this.

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config')->getSection('dev')->groups->my_module->label
```

If you look at the source of `getSection`

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config.php
public function getSections($sectionCode=null, $websiteCode=null, $storeCode=null)
{
    if (empty($this->_sections)) {
        $this->_initSectionsAndTabs();
    }

    return $this->_sections;
}
```

and follow the call stack through to `_initSectionsAndTabs`

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config.php
protected function _initSectionsAndTabs()
{
    $config = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml')
        ->applyExtends();

    Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_init_system_config', array('config' => $config));
    $this->_sections = $config->getNode('sections');
    $this->_tabs = $config->getNode('tabs');
}
```

You'll see this wrapper method eventually calls the `loadModulesConfiguration` method itself.  The additional `applyExtends` if an [old bit of meta-programming in the configuration you can read about here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_declared_modules_tutorial), which is part of [a longer series on configuration loading](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_config). (self-links, too long for a StackOverflow answer).

The reason I personally wouldn't use this to grab values out of the configuration is the event that's dispatched when you make this call

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_init_system_config', array('config' => $config));
```

This event may trigger code in your system that assumes you're loading the system configuration system in the backend admin console area.  If you **just** want to read the XML tree. simply loading it yourself and reading the values seems the way to go. Your use case, of course, may vary.

Comment: Found a different solution just after you posted this... what's the difference? Why is it better to use loadModulesConfiguration instead of getSingleton('adminhtml/config')?

Comment: @Benubird Updated the answer with more information and context.  The short version: The technique you found uses the `loadModulesConfiguration` method itself.

Answer (score 2):

As so often seems to be the case, I find the answer moments after posting the question...

This is how to get sections/dev/my_module/label:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config')->getSection('dev')->groups->my_module->label
```

As you can see, you need to use `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config')->getSection('dev')` to get the backend config (you can also use `->getSections()` to get all the sections to iterate over). This returns a Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object, which is the root of a tree of objects, accessible as shown. Just do a  print_r at any stage and you'll see the rest of the tree, which print_r formats like an array, although it's not.